# Entity Framework 6 - child property data not loading

Tags: sql, entity-framework

The ManagingAgent child property on the Complex entity is not being loaded with data.... possibly the result of too much mulled wine.

I have logged the SQL on the database calls and the SQL is returning the correct data.

LazyLoading is disabled.

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

Aggregate Root

```
public class Complex
{
    public Complex()
    {
        Forums = new List<Forum>();
        ManagingAgent = new ManagingAgent();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ComplexId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
    public int? PostCodeId { get; set; }
    public PostCode PostCode { get; set; }
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int? CountyId { get; set; }
    public County County { get; set; }
    public int? ManagingAgentId { get; set; }
    public ManagingAgent ManagingAgent { get; set; }
    public int? CountOfUnits { get; set; }
    public List<Forum> Forums { get; set; }     
}
```

Attempt 1. using Include...

```
public List<Complex> GetComplexesByUserId(Guid userId)
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        db.Database.Log = Logger;
        var complexIds = db.UserApartments.Where(r => r.UserId == userId)
                                          .Select(c => c.ComplexId).ToList();
        return db.Complexes.Where(c => complexIds.Contains(c.ComplexId))
                           .Include(m => m.ManagingAgent).ToList();
    }
}
```

Attempt 2 - explicitly loading ..same result (SQL returns data correctly but ManagingAgent isn't populated)

```
public List<Complex> GetComplexesByUserId(Guid userId)
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        db.Database.Log = Logger;
        var complexIds = db.UserApartments.Where(r => r.UserId == userId)
                                          .Select(c => c.ComplexId).ToList();

        var list = new List<Complex>();

        foreach (var id in complexIds)
        {
            var complex = db.Complexes.Find(id);
            db.Entry(complex).Reference(m => m.ManagingAgent).Load();
            list.Add(complex);
        }

        return list;                
    }
}
```

So, to force the load I am doing this.... not good..

```
foreach (var id in complexIds)
{
    var complex = db.Complexes.Find(id);
    var managingAgent = db.ManagingAgents.Find(complex.ManagingAgentId);
    complex.ManagingAgent = managingAgent;
    list.Add(complex);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use an `Include` after a `Where` call, but if it's supported in EF6 then ok, but perhaps you could try swapping the two --> `return db.Complexes.Include(m => m.ManagingAgent).Where(c => complexIds.Contains(c.ComplexId)).ToList();`

Comment: Do you have a foreign key relationship setup in the model? I don't see it defined anywhere in the above setup and that would explain the consistency of both versions not loading the child object. If there is no relationship, it doesn't know how/what to load.

Comment: @Kepri - you might have a point. I checked the schema diagram using the power tools and it looked fine. I have just checked the db and something doesn't look right. Complex has a foreign key to ManagingAgent but ManagingAgent has no foreign key to Complex. A Complex can have 0 or 1 ManagingAgent but a ManagingAgent can have 0 or many Complexes. Must be an issue with relationships.... need to try some different cardinalities//

Comment: @Silvermind .. yes, thats why I tried Attempt 2 to avoid using the include.

Comment: @Kepri - I have checked the context schema and the database. Both are correct. Back to the drawing board..

Comment: I did not remove it, I swapped it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line...

```
ManagingAgent = new ManagingAgent();
```

...from the constructor of the `Complex` entity. Then it will work. (Generally don't instantiate reference navigation properties in an entity default constructor. EF calls this constructor via reflection when it materializes the entity and "gets confused" if the navigation property already has a reference. I can't explain the "gets confused" better since I don't know the exact mechanism of object materialization with related entities, but the effect is that the loaded child column values are ignored because there is already an instantiated child entity, but just with the useless default values from the `ManagingAgent` constructor.)

Comment: Is this new in EF6? I ask because if you use the EF Power Tools to reverse engineer an existing database it will create the stubs to instantiate reference objects in the constructor like the above example.

Comment: @Khepri: No, it's not new. Are you sure about the EF Power Tools? It creates *empty collections*, yes, and that's not a problem. But I've never seen *references* in autogenerated code. See for instance the `Product`/`Category` example at the end of this post: http://romiller.com/2012/05/09/customizing-reverse-engineer-code-first-in-the-ef-power-tools/ `Product` doesn't have a constructor that instantiates a `Category`, only `Category` has a constructor with an empty list of `Product`s.

Comment: Ah, you're right. My mistake. I glanced at my auto-gen'd classes and just had a mini brain meltdown. Thanks.

Comment: @Slauma, yep you got it. Removed the nav props from the constructor and all was good again. Still not sure about the mechanism that instantiates those properties using reflection. I find the most confusing part of EF are the errors that it throws. The error in the case was that there was an issue with the referential integrity and multiplicity. Thanks